# Filtering Items from DataGridview to a DataTable produces Invalid Results

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have the following datagridview.
[image]

I need to filter and save rows separately that match Valid and Invalid property of the status column.
It do not have a datasource.So i'm creating a DataTable,filtering it and saving the results.But the filtering is not working as intended and contains results that does not match the expression

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //Populating Virtual Table 

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView4.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }
```

Now creating a Filtered Table containing results where column named Status equals "Valid"

```
 filtered = dt.Copy();
                DataTable filteredResults = new DataTable();
                DataTable filteredResults2 = new DataTable();
                // filtered.Columns.Remove("Status");

                var expression = string.Format("Status LIKE '%{0}%'", "Valid");
                if (filtered.Select(expression).Any())
                {
                    filteredResults = filtered.Select(expression).CopyToDataTable();                 

                }
```

But the filtered data table contains elements which has the Status column value "Invalid".What i'm i doing wrong ? Please advice.

Comment: A `LIKE` condition is similar to "Contains". "Invalid" contains "valid" so there you go.

Comment: @Crowcoder ohkay.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LIKE` in your expression. `LIKE` checks to see if the value **contains** the specified value. Use `=` instead.

Comment: Thanks but how to use `=` ? I have tried `Status ='%{0}%'", "Valid"` .This does not produce any output.

Comment: Try changing it to `var expression = "Status = 'Valid'";`